# Doing batch requests for mails/contacts/calendar using outlook rest api

Tags: rest, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi, office365-apps

> I've found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis) that says that the Office 365 REST API
>   supports batch requests. I have tried to use this to retrieve emails
>   using the Office 365 REST API, but so far I receive a "400 - Bad
>   Request" reply. Does this simply mean that the email part of the API
>   does not support batch requests yet? In any case the only examples on
>   the web are for Sharepoint I have found nothing about the Office 365
>   API. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to fetch contacts/calendar events also using batch requests. is it possible?

Comment: Batching works fine I use it you need to show the code your using that is failing if you want help with that.

Comment: @GlenScales  I use pagesize of 500 when I am listing the mails using outlook rest mail api but I used batch request for fetching full gmail mails earlier. So I was checking if I can implement the similar behaviour to minimize the http connection overhead. (we need 1 api request per message for gmail but that is not the case with exchange because mailfolders/{folder_id}/messages) returns all the property